# Sci-fi movie featuring a man with wings

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw an old-ish (dated looking, but in color) sci-fi movie in a bar this weekend that I'm looking to identify. Unfortunately, the sound was off, so I can't say for sure that what the country of origin is.

Here are some things I remember about it:

- Fairly pulpy feel.
- Set off-Earth
- Features a man with angel-type wings, wearing a loin cloth. He was carrying a woman through the sky.
- Other people wearing future-styled garb
- Some sort of a staring/willpower contest between a woman and a guy where they had palms pressed against each other. The woman seemed to be winning.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say it was set off-Earth; what where the clues that made it not-Earth as opposed to some future era?  You also describe it as "sci-fi;" were there any technological devices depicted?

Comment: Thanks. First question: no landscape, futuristic looking city. Could in theory be underground or in a base of some kind. Second question: hard to say, more about how people were dressed and the styling of the set. Certainly not hard sci-fi.

Comment: That "staring contest" was no staring contest .. it was future sex ..  lol

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just based on the description of an angel in a loincloth, I'm going to suggest it might be [*Barbarella*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062711/) (1968).

[image: Pygar with Barbarella]

[image: Pygar flying carrying Barbarella]

Quoting from the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarella_(film)#Plot) on Wikipedia:

> Barbarella leaves the planet and crashes into a labyrinth inhabited by outcasts exiled from Sogo. She is found by **Pygar, a blind angel** who has lost the will to fly. Pygar introduces her to Professor Ping, who offers to repair her ship. **Pygar flies Barbarella to Sogo**, a den of violence and debauchery, after she restores his will to fly by having sex with him.

I'm surprised, though, that you don't remember... *other* parts of the movie.

Comment: Nice! That's the one! As for the end of your answer, I'll just note that I was only catching bits and pieces at the bar, though I do now see what you mean...

Comment: They played Barbarella at a bar?... I mean I guess it has the word Bar in it twice :P

Comment: He didn't specify what sort of establishment his bar was ;-)

Comment: I've been meaning to watch this for _years_ - I guess now is the time!

Comment: Bar Barbarella!

Comment: "Barbarella, an astronaut from the 41st century, sets out to find and stop the evil scientist Durand Durand, whose Positronic Ray threatens to bring evil back into the galaxy." Like the band??

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "Naming their band after "Dr. Durand Durand", Milo O'Shea's character from the sci-fi film Barbarella (1968)..."  Yes, like the band.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the last bulletpoint (which places it very firmly as Barbarella!), this could also have been Flash Gordon, with Brian Blessed in wings:

[image]

[image]

Both films are cheesy space opera at its best.

Comment: Holy moley!  Searching youtube for "Brian Blessed Flash Gordon" brings up a _bunch of great stuff_ including ["Who wants to live forever?!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4nS9IbT-uk) - I had _no idea_!  Blessed is one of the _greats_! (And there's a bunch of _non_ Flash Gordon BB stuff on youtube too - look for his snooker commentary!)  IDC that this isn't the right answer to this question: Someone should _definitely_ ask the question for which this **is** the right answer!

Comment: @davidbak Very true. I remain unconvinced that there exists any question for which Brian Blessed is not at least one of the possible valid answers.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to potential answers based on a winged man carrying a woman, Terry Gilliam's *[Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_(1985_film))* could be a match if the scene with the wings was a more isolated memory. I don't think they did a palm-to-palm thing, though.

[image: Cover of Brazil DVD showing Jonathan in (dream) flight]

> In a dystopian, polluted, hyper-consumerist, overbearing bureaucratic totalitarian future somewhere in the 20th century, Sam Lowry is a low-level government employee who frequently dreams of himself as a winged warrior saving a damsel in distress. One day, shortly before Christmas, a fly becomes jammed in a teleprinter, which misprints a copy of an arrest warrant it was receiving. This leads to the arrest and death during interrogation of cobbler Archibald Buttle instead of renegade heating engineer and suspected terrorist Archibald Tuttle.

Comment: This question is starting to become a list for a great Sci-Fi movie night!